# UISearchBar customization code crashes in iOS7, works on iOS6

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar, ios7

I have an iOS application, built to support iOS5.1, and I was customizing the cancel button inside search bars.

The code I'm using and that works until iOS6.1 is the following:

```
id barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar =
    [UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn: [UISearchBar class], nil];
[barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar setTitle:
    [self localizedStringValueFor:@"Cancel"]];
```

Somehow the second line will cause a bad access exception, the `barButtonAppearanceInSearchBar` seems to be deallocated when I try to set the value for the button's text.

`localizedStringForValue` is a custom method that will return a String with the translation for the provided key or the key itself if not translation exists.

Now when I run the app on iOS7' simulator the app always crashes. Been trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong but no luck so far.

Comment: Maybe, but it has been working fine so far and I believe it is one very often mention solution for the problem of customizing the cancel button's text.

Answer (score 1):

`setTitle` is not a support [`UIAppearanceContainer`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/UIAppearanceContainer_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/macro/UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR) method. Only properties that are marked with `UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR` are supported.

You will have to set the title manually when you create the `UISearchBar`.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot find a way to set the cancel button's text on creation, any thing I'm missing in the documentation for the UISearchBar?